# Is there a particular way to convert 3-d array to 2-d array for clustering?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I have a 3-d array of shape=(3, 60000, 10) which needs to be 2-D so as to be able to visualize it when clustering.

I was planning on implementing the k-means clustering from scikit-learn to the 3-d array and read that it only takes in 2-D shape , I just wanted some advice as to whether there is a right way to do it ? I was planning on making it (60000,30) , but wanted a clarification before I go ahead.

Comment: Do not post 4 times the same question, edit your previous question instead and add some details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How I read it is that you have 10 features each consisting of 3d data. Do you intend to cluster all 10 features? If so reshape it such that you have 600000 x 3 points (assuming you want to separate in space). For example this

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, numpy as np

# 3x points
data = np.random.rand(100, 3, 10) + np.arange(10) # add arbitrary offset for "difference" in real data
data = np.moveaxis(data, -1, 1).reshape(-1, 3) 
n_clus = 10 # cluster in 10 --> fill in with your goal in mind
km = KMeans(n_clusters = n_clus).fit(data)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw = dict(projection = '3d'))
colors = plt.cm.tab20(np.linspace(0, 1, n_clus))
ax.scatter(*data.T, c = colors[km.labels_])
fig.show()
```

Yields[image]

Comment: need to project it onto 2-D space though,

Comment: You can project this in 2d slices if you want.  I leave that up to you as an exercise ;-).

Comment: Just minor comment, the code above clusters the 10 features in along its 3d coordinates. You can slice it to only visualize 2d pairs (xy,xz, yz). I assume this was the goal. You need to provide kmeans with the number of clusters. If you want to get the number of k that best fit the data have a look at model comparison on `sklearn`.

Answer (score 1):

`(600000 , 30)` is probably not a great idea. K-means clustering uses a distance metrics to define clusters, Euclidean distance normally, but when you increase number of variables in the second dimension you fall into a [curse of dimensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality) where results of clustering will stop making sense.

You can of course try (600000, 30) and see if it works, but if it doesn't, you'll need to do reduce dimensionality, for example by doing a [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) and use principal components to do clustering.

**EDIT**
I'll probably try and explain what I mean by dimensionality and the issues it causes since there appears to be some confusion.

A 2d array of size (100, 2) is a 2-dimensional data, i.e. it's 100 observations of 2 variables. The trend line between those points would be a 1d object (line) and you can plot it on a 2d plane. Similarly, a (100, 3) array is 3-dimensional with a trendline being a 2d plane and you can plot those points on a 3d chart.

Then (100, 100) array is 100-dimensional. A trend would be a 99-dimensional hyperplane and you cannot visualise even in principle. Now let's see what issues this causes. Let's define a simple function calculating Euclidean distance:

```
def distance(x, y):
    return sum((i - j)**2 for i, j in zip(x, y))**0.5
```

The function takes two iterables as arguments and calculates Euclidean distance between those. Now let's try with something simple:

```
v1 = (1, 1)
v2 = (2, 2)
v3 = (100, 100)
v4 = (120, 120)

>> distance(v1, v2)
Out: 1.4142135623730951
>> distance(v1, v3)
Out: 140.0071426749364
>> distance(v1, v4)
Out: 168.2914139223983
```

If we make these tuples 3 dimensional keeping the same values in all dimensions, distances become respectively: 1.73, 171.47, 206.11.

Now for the fun part - let's add a bunch of dimensions filled with "1"s:

```
v1 = [1, 1, 1] + list(1 for i in range(47))
v2 = [2, 2, 2] + list(1 for i in range(47))
v2 = [100, 100, 100] + list(1 for i in range(47))
v4 = [120, 120, 120] + list(1 for i in range(47))

>>> distance(v1, v2)
171.47302994931886

>>> distance(v1, v3)
175.16278143486988

>>> distance(v1, v4)
206.11404610069638
```

So here we increased dimensions without adding additional information to separate variables an suddenly what appeared as two distinct clusters are not so defined any more, in fact v1, v2 and v3 appear more like they belong together and v4 being an outsider.

This will also happen in most cases, unless the higher dimensions continue the pattern of the first three, i.e. (1, 1, 1...), (2, 2, 2,..), (100, 100, 100...), (120, 120, 120,...). But in most cases you will see distances shrink and clusters become indistinguishable.

Comment: Then how would you go about it then? what could be the right way to reshape it?

Comment: The curse of dimensionality does not imply that results don't make sense in higher dimensions, it just relates the dimensionality to the induced sparsity due to the growing of dimensions. Data can be perfectly well clustered in high dimensions with good representation. In addition, the number of dimensions here are merely 3 which is totally do-able. See my answer for an example.

Comment: @cvanelteren, I disagree with your interpretation of dimensionality. The initial dataset of the poster it's a 3d array but it has 10 variables in the second dimension. These are the 'dimensions' that the "curse" is referring to because if you want to plot those - it will have to be in 10 dimensions. You should try working with any genetic dataset where you have expressions of hundreds of genes. Even when the clusters are as easy as can be, distance-based clustering methods fail to converge. You absolutely have to do a PCA to reduce dimensionality.

Comment: @cvanelteren, in your example you worked with a 3 dimensional data so of course it works fine.

Comment: @cvanelteren, I amended my original answer with the explanation of what I mean in detail.

Comment: Yes I agree with i.i.d. variables in high dimensions things like euclidean distance becomes troublesome (as dimensions grows to infinity), and one should look elsewhere for reducing the space. It turns out however, for correlated variables the curse of dimensionality is not that bad, i.e. see: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/sam.11161